# How to convert to unicode escape?

Tags: php, unicode, escaping, unicode-escapes

How can I do this in PHP?

string --> \u0073\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067

Tried using json_encode, but it doesn't handle all characters.
I've decided so far. How to make it better?

```
<?php
$text = 'string';
$string = str_split($text);
foreach($string as &$ch)
   $ch = "\u00".dechex(ord($ch));
echo implode('',$string);
```

I did it! The issue is resolved.

```
$text = 'hello 王先生';
$str = bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE', $text));
$var = str_split($str, 4);
foreach($var as &$ch){
    $ch = '\u'.$ch;
}
echo implode("", $var);
```

Comment: If it is about PHP, you should use also the PHP tag. And it seems you are solving some problem in a "interesting" way. Usually you do no need to escape the printable ASCII characters (really no need `\` and `u` and `a` to `f` are also ASCII and they must be understood of the exercise fail anyway. Maybe this is an intermediate step to get codepoints (maybe in hexadecimal)? Or do you need some string properties (length in codepoints? etc. Maybe if you tell us what you are trying to do, we can explain a better way without passing from such ugly escaping.

Comment: Yes, this is not a trivial conversion, I want to supplement the encoding converter.
There is no way in the PHP documentation to do such a conversion directly. So I need to do this through intermediate coding.
Maybe something similar to this: string --> HEX 0x.. or HEX \.. --> unicode escape
I want to know the easiest and shortest way.